# Object arry values to style elements

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to get the checked checkboxes and to match its name to a object array to be able to retrieve some values. Sample fiddle.

How do I use those values to create a span element and update the colour set the position based on the checked checkboxes?

```js
      var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("fruits"); 
      const item = { 
            "lychee" :{ price:10, pos:80, colCode:'ff0000' }, 
            "orange" :{ price:12, pos:60, colCode:'00ff00' },
            "apple"  :{ price:8, pos:40, colCode:'ff6600' },
            "mango"  :{ price:12, pos:60, colCode:'00ff00' },
            "banana" :{ price:4, pos:80, colCode:'ff0000' }
       };
    
      let result = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=fruits]:checked")]
      .map(chk => (
          var marker = document.createElement('span');
          marker.style.color = colCode:${item[chk.value].colCode}, //does not work
          marker.style.marginLeft = pos:${item[chk.value].pos}px ) //does not work
      );
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lychee">Lychee <br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="orange" checked>Orange <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="apple">Apple <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="mango" checked>Mango <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana">Banana
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the span? It's quite unclear. You don't append it or anything.

Comment: @aviya.developer Thanks for your response. I want to append it to `document.getElementById('wrapper')` and then color it and set the left margin.

Comment: But a span must have some text in it. Can you describe the end result you wish to achieve? Also there is no element with the id 'wrapper' in your html.

Comment: @aviya.developer Thanks. The span can be styled so the text wont be necessary. `span{
  width:20px;  height:20px;  border: 1px solid #ccc;  display: block;}`. The `#wrapper` was for illustrative purposes only. My requirement is to be able to know how to use the values from the object array.

Comment: No need to use a `span`, if you intend to make it a `block`. Just use a `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very unclear as to what your code aims to accomplish since you haven't provided the desired result, but I can help you get rid of the syntactical errors.

Your code has the following problems:

- You're not using the arrow function correctly. If you plan to use more than one statement in it, or define variables, you should use braces and then return the result you want.
- You're not using template literals correctly. For them to work, they have to be enclosed in backticks.

```js
var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("fruits");

const item = { 
    "lychee": { price: 10, pos: 80, colCode: "ff0000" }, 
    "orange": { price: 12, pos: 60, colCode: "00ff00" },
    "apple": { price: 8, pos: 40, colCode: "ff6600" },
    "mango": { price: 12, pos: 60, colCode: "00ff00" },
    "banana": { price: 4, pos: 80, colCode: "ff0000" }
};

let result = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=fruits]:checked")].map(chk => {
    /* Create a <span> element. */
    var marker = document.createElement("span");
    
    /* Set the properties using template literals. */
    marker.style.color = `#${item[chk.value].colCode}`;
    marker.style.marginLeft = `${item[chk.value].pos}px`;
    
    /* Put some content into the <span>. */
    marker.textContent= "Content";
    
    /* Append the <span> into the wrapper. */
    wrapper.appendChild(marker);
    
    /* Return the <span> so that it's cached inside the results array. */
    return marker;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lychee" checked>Lychee <br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="orange" >Orange <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="apple" checked>Apple <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="mango" checked>Mango <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana">Banana

<div id = "wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: +10 Thanks. Sorry about the question not being clear. I want to append a new span to `document.getElementById('wrapper')` and then color it and set the left margin. So if 3 checkboxes are selected it there should be 3 spans with the relevant color according to the object array value.

Comment: See my snippet. Does it achieve your desired result?

Comment: Great... you certainly answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, @jules2x 